# What was the "Great river of the Ocean" shown to Jonah?

Tags: midrash, yonah-jonah-book-of

The [Midrash Tanchuma in Vayikra](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Vayikra.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) discusses the wonders shown to Jonah by the fish which swallowed him after having saved it from the Leviathan (*see the Midrash [ibid.] for further elaboration)*.

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org)*)

> אמר לו לדג, הריני הצלתיך מפיו של לויתן, הראני כל מה שבים ובתהומות. והראהו נהר גדול של מימי אוקינוס, שנאמר: תהום יסובבני (יונה ב, ו)‏
>
> *[Jonah] said to the fish, "behold, I saved you from the mouth of the Leviathan, show me all that is in the sea and its depths", **and [the fish] showed him the great river of the waters of the ocean**, as it is written "the depths surrounded me" ([Jonah 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Jonah.2.6?lang=bi))*

## My Question:

What is "the great river of the waters of the ocean?" is it discussed anywhere else in the Midrashim describing its location/function?

Comment: Underwater River Flows Along Mexico’s Ocean Floor -
 https://mymodernmet.com/anatoly-beloshchin-mexico-yucatan-cenote-angelita/

Comment: עיין רש"י בכורות ט. ד"ה בי בליעי, ועיין תוס' שם לגבי ה "Bermuda triangle"

Comment: Are you trying to stay in the context of the midrash? Typically, "The Great Fish" (דאגה and הדג הגדול) is an allegory for worries and concerns. And the Great Sea is an allegory for material sustenance (money, food, clothing, etc). In that context, it would be discussing macroeconomic models which encompass and control every detail of material sustenance.

Comment: There's something about rivers in oceans in Kohelet Rabba on the verse כל הנחלים הולכים אל הים ([here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/kohelet/1b-2.htm)), but it doesn't mention explicitly "the great river"

Comment: @רבותמחשבות it sounds like  (visually) Danny's answer . I'm certain theres something in the Likutei Moharan about this Midrash too.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi This also follows the explanation of the Gra and Ibn Ezra concerning these posukim in Yonah 2:4-6. That the depths of the sea are the depths of Olam HaZeh as contrasted with the Heavens. The river (Nahar Dinor) is that which separates and divides between Olam HaZeh and Gehinnom. This is, to a large extent, discussing the kind of judgement that happens for Rashaim. They are judged according to what they do in the material, physical world. You should also look at the discussion in Kehillat Yaacov about rivers generally being associated with the 5 Gevurot of Imma.

Comment: And all this would be in keeping with the idea expressed in Shabbat 31a, about what is the first question asked by the Heavenly Court after departing this world? Were you honest in business relations?

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi FYI, that Kehillat Yaacov is by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles. And according to what I just saw in Peirush HaMekuballim b'Niglah, the Rashaim spoken of here, in Yonah, are the non-Jews. That this is about how non-Jews are judged as contrasted to Jews. And this is based upon Yonah 3:9.

Comment: See sefer אוצרות המפרשים on page 192: https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/619386/p/192/t/0.091228863082107651234/fs/mlutiEgkGpSaT7SEk9FEDX9x1hZMRQIrNTGdmnmF9qcu/start/110/end/135/c